# If checkbox with name A is selected then deselect all the checkboxes with name B. How to do it?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have 4 checkboxes in my HTMl. 3 of them have name "A" and 4th one has name "B". I want that when user selects checkbox with name "B" then all the checkboxes with name "A" should be deselected (if any selected) automatically.

Also, if user clicks on any checkbox with name "A", then automatically checkbox "B" should be deselected if it was selected previously.

Comment: show what you have done

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="A"  value="1"> opt1 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="A"  value="2"> opt2 <br/>              <input type="checkbox" name="A"  value="3"> opt3 <br/> .            <input type="checkbox" name="B"  value="4"> None of these <br/>

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function Select_All(source) {
   document.getElementByName("a1").checked = false;
   document.getElementByName("a2").checked = false;
   document.getElementByName("a3").checked = false;



</script>
function turn_none_Off(source){
    document.getElementByName("none").checked = false;
</script language="JavaScript">



<input type="checkbox" name="a1"  onClick="turn_none_Off(this)" value="1"> A <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="a2" onClick="turn_none_Off(this)" value="2"> A <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="a3" onClick="turn_none_Off(this)" value="3"> A <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name ="none" onClick="Select_All(this)" /> None of the Above <br/>
```

Comment: Hey thanks. Can you write the full code for turn_off() function and please explain what is select_all() selecting .

Comment: I ma new to HTML. So please elaborate

Comment: select_all() is a function that loops through all the checkboxes and makes sure they are checked

Comment: But I don't need this functionality. What I want is that suppose if I have 4 checkboxes - option1,option2,option3 with name A and "None of the above" option with name B. Then, if "None of the above" checkbox is selected, then automatically any checkbox with name "A" should get deselected. And if user clicks on any of the checkbox with name "A",  then "None of the Above" checkbox should get deselected if it was selected before.

Comment: Here is my HTML code

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="A" value="1"> opt1 <br/> <input type="checkbox" name="A" value="2"> opt2 <br/> <input type="checkbox" name="A" value="3"> opt3 <br/> . <input type="checkbox" name="B" value="4"> None of these <br/>